# Add a count of one in every iteration in while loop, to dynamic array key

Tags: php

Hi I am making a polling functionality. In the below code I am trying to get count of answers by storing the key of array $count as **id** of the answer and **+=** to count how many times it was chosen as an answer.

The problem that I am having is that **$count[$option_id] += 1;** doesn't work. Not sure what I am doing wrong with the logic. In the database the records exist and I can confirm that query run fine and gets the result.

There are 2 answers possible per vote. For eg: lets take answer with Id 1 and 2. So, in the end, it should output something like

```
details: {1: 20, 2: 50}
```

This means that 20 people have voted for Answer 1 and 50 people for 2.

Any help will be great, Thanks

```
$answer_count = 0;
$count = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM `votes` where ques_id = 55";
$stmt = $this->db_obj->query_exec($query);

while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
    $answer_count++;
    $option_id = $info['option_id'];
    $count[$option_id] += 1;
}
return json_encode(array("success" => "1","total" => $answer_count,"details" => $count));
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is never a great description of a problem. Please specify what happens (what errors do you get?).

Comment: Where are you _initializing_ `$count[$option_id]` with a start value? You can not “add 1” to a value that is not even set.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware understand what you mean. I have the errors on in the page but it doesn't show any PHP or AJAX error. It just doesn't return the values as mentioned in the last line of code although when I comment **$count[$option_id] += 1;** then the return works.

Comment: _“but it doesn't show any PHP or AJAX error”_ - where did you _look_ for errors? Did you actually check the response to the AJAX request in the network panel of your browser dev tools …?

Comment: As @04FX said, you are referencing an index that doesn't yet exist. You need to check if that index is set and if not, set an initial value.

Comment: `echo json_encode(....................................);`

Comment: @MER I have edited the question and added the example of what I am looking for. and thanks for the suggestions. I will check n get back !!

Comment: Also, probably just `SELECT option_id, COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE ques_id = 55 GROUP BY option_id`

Comment: Great idea @AbraCadaver - better to let the DB do the work!

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks for this great idea, not sure why was I complicating things! It works fine now :-) Really appreciate it !!